# Editing an attached file

Tags: trello

I am trying out Trello to see if it provides what I currently get in shared server. I have added some documents that would require user updated but appears as Read Only when open, is there a way to share an attached file for editing?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but the share must be done separately via the cloud.

- e.g. you can attach a google doc, it must be shared and edited via Google docs.

[image]